# Dimming for high power led

Tags: arduino, mosfet, led, dimming

I've tried dimming led using driver(model jls-7265-50w) and using simple circuit with mosfet IRF540 transistor on output of driver. But this circuit didn't work well. When i decreasing pwm around pwm = 80 , led start blinking. and mosfet transistor started heating while blinking. then mosfet burnt out.

I used this circuit before on 12V led to dimming and it worked well.

I think problem is in led driver

how can i dimming high power led using mosfet powered by led driver?

thank you guys and pls forgive about my english . I'am still learning.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dim a constant-current LED driver in this way as the driver will simply increase its output voltage when the MOSFET disconnects the LED, thereby sending the FET into avalanche breakdown, which causes excessive power dissipation. Smoothing inductors at the output of the LED driver make this worse. The blinking can be explained by the LED driver going into a protective error state when the LED is suddenly disconnected.

Additionally, when the MOSFET then turns back on, any charge stored in the output capacitors of the driver will be discharged rapidly, further increasing the dissipation in the MOSFET and also shortening the lifespan of the LEDs.

So, in short: Don't do this with constant-current LED drivers, it's not going to work. You might instead want to build your own LED driver based on a dimmable boost-mode LED driver IC.

Comment: That MOSFET is good for 100V.

Comment: @MOSFET It is, yes. The problem is that the MOSFET forms a boost converter with the output smoothing inductor of the LED driver. All of the output power of this "parasitic" boost converter gets dumped directly into the MOSFET via avalanche breakdowns. That's why it works at 100% PWM (where the parasitic boost converter is shorted), but fails at lower settings. This also indicates that the FET's on-resistance is not the issue here, despite the low gate voltage. (If that was the issue, it'd fail at 100% already.)

Comment: I interpreted this as the Uno was the LED driver. But I still hold my position that the MOSFET is under-driven by the Arduino.

Comment: @MOSFET I fully agree, the MOSFET also needs a proper driver. It's just that the circuit is flawed to begin with and no amount of proper driving of that FET can save it.

Comment: thank you very much for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your Arduino doesn't provide enough juice to properly switch the MOSFET. You either need a gate driver for the transistor. Or you can make your own with some cheap, non-critical parts. Try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2magB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When your MOSFET is getting hot, that means it is not all the way off or all the way on. So its operating in it's ohmic region burning power. The MOSFET requires enough voltage on its gate to fully conduct that the Arduino GPIO's can't supply (3.3V or 5V is not enough). This circuit boosts the voltage seen by the MOSFET but can still be controlled by the low-voltage of the Arduino.

Comment: thank you for your help sir.  i will try this

Comment: @PurevkhuuBatmunkh Yeah. The idea is to PWM the GPIO and the whole circuit behaves like a LED driver. No additional circuitry required.

Answer (score 0):

An IRF540 has a threshold voltage which ranges from 2.0 V to 4.0 V. If your Arduino Uno drives the gate to 5 V, and the threshold is 4.0 V, the MOSFET will conduct, but will still have considerable resistance. This will cause heating, and may cause the MOSFET to fail. You should use a MOSFET driver to boost both the voltage and current from the levels available from the UNO to the levels required by the MOSFET. I suggest driving the gate to at least 7 V, if not higher.

In addition to possibly needing a higher gate voltage, the current available from a GPIO pin from an Arduino Uno is probably insufficient to turn the MOSFET on **FAST**. This is especially true when using the MOSFET to switch a high voltage (like 70 V!). When a MOSFET turns on slowly it heats up more, again risking failure. The small current available from the GPIO pin has another problem when driving a power MOSFET. Without a resistor between the GPIO pin and the gate of the MOSFET, the GPIO pin might burn out.

Comment: Standard drive voltage for a power FET like the IRF540 is 10 V, so that's what I would go with if a 10 V supply can be obtained. The common 12 V will work perfectly well too; the IRF540 has a maximum gate voltage of 20 V.

Comment: i see. thank you for your help
but i have one question
 i used this IRF540 mosfet before to dimming 12V led with using GPIO pin arduino. and it worked fine. there was no heat and i could fully controlled led brightness and dimming. 
if there was problem between gpio pin and mosfet gate,  why mosfet didn't heat up ?

Comment: Switching a higher voltage will generally produce more heat than switching a lower voltage. Switching a higher voltage with a MOSFET will also be a bit slower than switching a lower voltage with the same MOSFET, because there is parasitic capacitance between the gate and drain. Slower switching also means more heating. Also, were the "on" currents the same? Or different?